# abstract factory with handle body idiom

Tags: design-patterns, factory, object-oriented-analysis, pimpl-idiom

I have an abstract factory pattern hidden behind a handle-body idiom like the following:

```
 FactoryHandle <>--------------- AbstractFactory 
  {+ createCommonThing() }            /|\    {+ createCommonThing() }
                                       |
                                       | <<inherits>>
                            ------------------------
                            |                      |
                  ConcreteFactory1             ConcreteFactory2
                  {                            {
                   + createCommonThing()        + createCommonThing()
                   + createFactory1Thing()      + createFactory2Thing()  
                  }                            }
```

Here *FactoryHandle* is injected with a *ConcreteFactory* (body) upon construction. It is able to expose only *createCommonThing()* method since it can be the only one present in the abstract base factory class without violating Liskov Substitutability principle.

My question is: How do I cleanly expose the Concrete Factory specific methods like *createFactory1Thing* and *createFactory2Thing*?

Should I have a separate handle class such as *Factory1SpecificHandle* which is composed of *ConcreteFactory1* and exposes only the factory1 specific methods like *createFactory1Thing()*? And do the same thing for *Factory2SpecificHandle*? So, the client uses *FactoryHandle* if only common methods are to be used or *Factory1SpecificHandle* if specific methods are to be used. This somehow feels like a bad design.

```
Factory1SpecificHandle <>------------------ConcreteFactory1
{+ createFactory1Thing()}                  {
                                            + createCommonThing()
                                            + createFactory1Thing()
                                           }
```

What would you suggest as a clean design here? If the question is unclear, please let me know and I can elaborate further. Thanks.

Comment: Removed [tag:c++] tag, since I can't spot anything specifically c++ related in your questiion.

Comment: There is no way to define a common interface for specific things (like ``createSpecificThing()``)?  Clients should be restricted to create specific things?

Comment: @GüntherFranke You are right. But I am not trying to create a common interface to the specific things. I am creating separate handles for factory1 specific things and for factory2 specific things. This will work okay. But I don't think this is a good design. I wonder if Abstract Factory behind handle-body is an ideal design for this case or something else would be a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no common interface, I think it's cleaner to separate the factories (see UML diagram below).

Each interface (`AbstractFactory1`, `AbstractFActory2`) 
defines both the common and specific creation operations.

Clients work with these interfaces. There is no need to refer to concrete classes via handlers.

To control (restrict) access to a factory object, a Proxy 
 (similar to the Handle Body pattern) can be used (see Proxy at http://w3sdesign.com).

[image]

Comment: You are right. I did consider keeping the factories separate. Can you elaborate a bit on the proxy aspect here? Do you mean having *AbstractFactory1* and *AbstractFactory2* served to the client using a proxy class which provides all the interfaces but restricts the access to the interfaces based on which AbstractFactory it chooses?

Comment: A proxy for each interface. The proxy implements the interface by forwarding requests to the interface (or not if access isn't allowed). Clients work through the proxy object.